# Unable to access inner JSON value in JSON array - Typescript(Using Angular 8)

Tags: json, angular, group-by, angular8, jsonparser

I am trying to use the group by function on a `JSON array` using the inner `JSON` value as a key as shown below. But unable to read the inner `JSON` value. Here is my `JSON array`.

```
NotificationData = [ 
   { 
      "eventId":"90989",
      "eventTime":"2019-12-11T11:20:53+04:00",
      "eventType":"yyyy",
      "event":{ 
         "ServiceOrder":{ 
            "externalId":"2434",
            "priority":"1"
         }
      }
   },
   { 
      "eventId":"6576",
      "eventTime":"2019-12-11T11:20:53+04:00",
      "eventType":"yyyy",
      "event":{ 
         "ServiceOrder":{ 
            "externalId":"78657",
            "priority":"1"
         }
      }
   }
]
```

### GroupBy Logic:

```
const groupBy = (array, key) => {
  return array.reduce((result, currentValue) => {
    (result[currentValue[key]] = result[currentValue[key]] || []).push(
      currentValue
    );
    return result;
  }, {});
};

const serviceOrdersGroupedByExternalId = groupBy(this.NotificationData, 'event.ServiceOrder.externalId');
                                 //this line of code is not working as
                             // it is unable to locate the external id value.
```

### Desired output

```
{ "2434":[{
     "eventId":"90989",
     "eventTime":"2019-12-11T11:20:53+04:00",
     "eventType":"yyyy",
     "event":{
        "ServiceOrder":{ "priority":"1" }
     } 
  }],
  "78657":[{
     "eventId":"6576",
     "eventTime":"2019-12-11T11:20:53+04:00",
     "eventType":"yyyy", 
     "event":{
        "ServiceOrder":{ "priority":"1" }
     }
  }]
}
```

Comment: can you tell the desired output?

Comment: {
"2434":[
   { 
      "eventId":"90989",
      "eventTime":"2019-12-11T11:20:53+04:00",
      "eventType":"yyyy",
      "event":{ 
         "ServiceOrder":{ 
            "priority":"1"
         }
      }
   }],
   "78657":[
   { 
      "eventId":"6576",
      "eventTime":"2019-12-11T11:20:53+04:00",
      "eventType":"yyyy",
      "event":{ 
         "ServiceOrder":{ 
            "priority":"1"
         }
      }
   }]
   
}

Answer (score 1):

Does this solves your purpose?

```
let group = NotificationData.reduce((r, a) => {
  let d = r[a.event.ServiceOrder.externalId] = [...r[a.event.ServiceOrder.externalId] || [], a];
  return r;
 }, {});
 console.log(group);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It works as expected. Could you please brief me about the code since I am a beginner?

Comment: You are welcome. For better understanding please visit here https://www.consolelog.io/group-by-in-javascript/

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
result = {};

constructor() {
  let externalIds = this.NotificationData.flatMap(item => item.event.ServiceOrder.externalId);

  externalIds.forEach(id => {
      var eventData = this.NotificationData.filter(
        x => x.event.ServiceOrder.externalId == id
      ).map(function(item) {
        delete item.event.ServiceOrder.externalId;
        return item;
      });
      this.result[id] = eventData;
  });
}
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jqm1um?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)**